# groupBy json data then map in React component

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to group my JSON data so that all staff in the same 'department' are in an object together. Then I want to map through the data so I can display it on my webpage.

At the moment i'm getting the error 'cannot read property of map undefined'

my JSON data:

```
people:[  
  {  
     id:"a0bef",
     title:"cleaner",
     department:"facilities",

  },
  {  
     id:"a0beg",
     title:"maintenance",
     department:"facilities",

  },
  {  
     id:"a0beh",
     title:"cleaner",
     department:"facilities",

  },
  {  
     id:"a0bei",
     title:"chef",
     department:"kitchen",

  },
  {  
     id:"a0bej",
     title:"waitress",
     department:"kitchen",

  }
]
```

which I would like to look like:

```
people:[  
  "facilities":[  
     {  
        id:"a0bef",
        title:"cleaner"
     },
     {  
        id:"a0beg",
        title:"maintenance"
     },
     {  
        id:"a0beh",
        title:"cleaner"
     }
  ],
  "kitchen":[  
     {  
        id:"a0bei",
        title:"chef"
     },
     {  
        id:"a0bej",
        title:"waitress"
     }
  ]
]
```

this is what I have tried:

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'

class PeopleList extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render () {
    const { peoplelist } = this.props
    const people = _.groupBy(peoplelist, 'department')
    return (
      <div>
        { Object.people.map(function (person, key) {
          return (
            <div className='row' key={key}>
              <div className='col-md-6'>{person.department}</div>
              <div className='col-md-4'>{person.title}</div>
            </div>
          )
        }) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default PeopleList
```

Comment: What is `Object.people` ? Did you mean to use `keys` or `values` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `Object.people is not a valid syntax`.

`people` after `const people = _.groupBy(peoplelist, 'department')` will be an Object. You need to get all the values of the object (`using Object.values(people)`); which will give you an array of person. Then, map through that array to get the desired output.

The function will be modified to

```
Object.values(people).map(function (deptArray) { 
    return deptArray.map(function (person) {
      return (
        <div className='row' key={some-unique-key}>
          <div className='col-md-6'>{person.department}</div>
          <div className='col-md-4'>{person.title}</div>
        </div>
      )            
    })
})
```

**Note:** In the above case you won't be able to use array indexes as the key, because the keys will be repeated (and so, I have removed it from my solution).

Hope it helps. Revert for any clarifications/doubts.

Answer (score 1):

> At the moment i'm getting the error 'cannot read property of map
>   undefined'

This is due to this line in your return statement `{ Object.people.map(function (person, key)`

```
const people = _.groupBy(peoplelist, 'department')
```

Above will you an object of 2 arrays i.e `facilities` and `kitchen`.

So you can do the following for displaying the data.

```
Object.values(people).map(dept => {
  dept.map((person, key) => {
    return (
      <div className='row' key={key}>
        <div className='col-md-6'>{person.department}</div>
        <div className='col-md-4'>{person.title}</div>
      </div>
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group your items by department and then display a list of persons ordered by department, then you need to map twice. Once over the departments, and then once over each person in each department.

To iterate over the departments, you will need to use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Here is an example using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to implement `groupBy`:

```js
const people = [
  { id: "a0bef", title: "cleaner", department: "facilities" },
  { id: "a0beg", title: "maintenance", department: "facilities" },
  { id: "a0beh", title: "cleaner", department: "facilities" },
  { id: "a0bei", title: "chef", department: "kitchen" },
  { id: "a0bej", title: "waitress", department: "kitchen" }
]

function groupBy(data, key) {
  return data.reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x[key]] = [...(acc[x[key]] || []), x];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

class PeopleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const people = groupBy(this.props.people, 'department')
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        {Object.entries(people).map(([dep, staff]) => {
          return (
            <div className='dep' key={dep}>
              <span className='dep-name'>{dep}</span>
              {staff.map(person => {
                return (
                  <div className='row' key={person.id}>
                    <div className='col-xs-6'>Dep: {person.department}</div>
                    <div className='col-xs-4'>Title: {person.title}</div>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PeopleList people={people} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.dep {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.dep-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>
```